# Cannot open Windows Installer (msiexec.exe)

Tags: windows-installer, installation, windows-7-x64

I am having a problem where windows installer will not open. I am running Windows 7 Home Premium and when I try to open msiexec.exe, I get this message :

```
Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.7601.17514 

msiexec /Option <Required Parameter> [Optional Parameter]

Install Options
    </package | /i> <Product.msi>
        Installs or configures a product
    /a <Product.msi>
        Administrative install - Installs a product on the network
    /j<u|m> <Product.msi> [/t <Transform List>] [/g <Language ID>]
        Advertises a product - m to all users, u to current user
    </uninstall | /x> <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Uninstalls the product
Display Options
    /quiet
        Quiet mode, no user interaction
    /passive
        Unattended mode - progress bar only
    /q[n|b|r|f]
        Sets user interface level
        n - No UI
        b - Basic UI
        r - Reduced UI
        f - Full UI (default)
    /help
        Help information
Restart Options
    /norestart
        Do not restart after the installation is complete
    /promptrestart
        Prompts the user for restart if necessary
    /forcerestart
        Always restart the computer after installation
Logging Options
    /l[i|w|e|a|r|u|c|m|o|p|v|x|+|!|*] <LogFile>
        i - Status messages
        w - Nonfatal warnings
        e - All error messages
        a - Start up of actions
        r - Action-specific records
        u - User requests
        c - Initial UI parameters
        m - Out-of-memory or fatal exit information
        o - Out-of-disk-space messages
        p - Terminal properties
        v - Verbose output
        x - Extra debugging information
        + - Append to existing log file
        ! - Flush each line to the log
        * - Log all information, except for v and x options
    /log <LogFile>
        Equivalent of /l* <LogFile>
Update Options
    /update <Update1.msp>[;Update2.msp]
        Applies update(s)
    /uninstall <PatchCodeGuid>[;Update2.msp] /package <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Remove update(s) for a product
Repair Options
    /f[p|e|c|m|s|o|d|a|u|v] <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Repairs a product
        p - only if file is missing
        o - if file is missing or an older version is installed (default)
        e - if file is missing or an equal or older version is installed
        d - if file is missing or a different version is installed
        c - if file is missing or checksum does not match the calculated value
        a - forces all files to be reinstalled
        u - all required user-specific registry entries (default)
        m - all required computer-specific registry entries (default)
        s - all existing shortcuts (default)
        v - runs from source and recaches local package
Setting Public Properties
    [PROPERTY=PropertyValue]

Consult the Windows ® Installer SDK for additional documentation on the
command line syntax.

Copyright © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Portions of this software are based in part on the work of the Independent JPEG Group.
```

When I click OK, the window closes. I need to create an installer package, but I can't even get Windows Installer to run properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two different things you are trying to do. If you are trying to create a windows installer package, then what you need is called as WiX. WiX is a open source available from Microsoft that contains set of tools like Candle and Light which enable you to build an installer package. You need to author the installer package in XML and provide that as input to WiX toolset.

WiX can produce out put in several different formats, like self extractor or MSI packages.

Once an MSI package is available that package is given to MSIInstaller for installing the package. In using above command you are trying to run a MSI package. The fact that it is showing command line options tells that you are able to run the MSIInstaller on your machine without any problems

Answer (score 1):

msiexec is really just the service to install an msi.

Search for MSI Authoring Tools on Google to get what you need.
The easy to use Tools cost money. But as mentioned the "wix" toolset is a good free alternative.